# Disabling a link client-side

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-ajax

I have a button that when click will hide all the Link in the entire page.

```
<input type="button" class="switch" value="switch" isValue="0" />
```

And the script for that is:

```
 <script>
    $(document).on('click', '.switch', function () {
        var v = $(".switch").attr("isValue");
        if (v == 1) {
            $(".switch").attr("isValue", "0");
            $(".dim").show();
        }
        else {
            $(".switch").attr("isValue", "1");
            $(".dim").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Problems:

1. I need A switch to hide all my Links
2. I need my Links to look like it is disabled not Hidden.

What I need:

1. How can I replace the button to make it a switch?
2. Since whenever I click the button it will hide all the Links in my page right? can I possibly just use css so it will appear that its just disabled not hidden since disabled wont work on link.

I don't want my links to be hidden but only disabled.

Comment: What do you mean by "make it a switch"? There's no such element type.

Comment: oh ok, how about the second problem?

Comment: Use `pointer-events: none;` in CSS to prevent clicking on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by a switch. Maybe you can use radio buttons?

To answer your second question, you can use the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS style to make the link non-clickable.

```
.dim.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Then the JS would be:

```
$(document).on('click', '.switch', function () {
    var v = $(".switch").attr("isValue");
    if (v == 1) {
        $(".switch").attr("isValue", "0");
        $(".dim").removeClass("disabled");
    }
    else {
        $(".switch").attr("isValue", "1");
        $(".dim").addClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

You also shouldn't create custom attributes like `isValue`. If you need to store custom data in an element, use `.data()`. So `$(".switch").attr("isValue", "1")` becomes `$(".switch").data("isValue", 1);`

Comment: You mean something that looks like `[ ON | OFF ]`? There are libraries that will render radio buttons like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no disabled attribute for hyperlinks. If you don't want something to be linked then you'll need to remove its href or replace href to data-href attribute when you want to active again then replce it with href attribute.